# Is it possible to add action hook before vagrant halt/suspend

Tags: vagrant

i would like to trigger action on my VM *before* the suspend or halt action takes effect.

I see action hook i could use but they are all *after* the actions are done https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/plugins/action-hooks.html.
Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe most of those hooks are for plugin development - what you're looking at is the [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) so if you want to have action done before suspend or halt :

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Your existing Vagrant configuration
  ...

  # run some script before the guest is halted
  config.trigger.before :halt do
    info "Dumping the database before destroying the VM..."
    run_remote  "bash /vagrant/cleanup.sh"
  end

  # run some script before the guest is suspended
  config.trigger.before :suspend do
    info "Dumping the database before destroying the VM..."
    run_remote  "bash /vagrant/cleanup.sh"
  end

  # clean up files on the host after the guest is destroyed
  config.trigger.after :destroy do
    run "rm -Rf tmp/*"
  end

  # start apache on the guest after the guest starts
  config.trigger.after :up do
    run_remote "service apache2 start"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also try to use udev events on guest machine.
This one can be done with provisioning when the `vagrant up` is done for the first time (or later with `vagrant provision`.
For example I'm restarting php5-fpm after nfs mounts directory with code.

I think you could also use systemd on guest OS (if you're using OS that has systemd of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at:

https://github.com/lqbweb/vagrant_hook

It is a basic and simple vagrant plugin that proves how to attach to a certain vagrant chain action.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to use `config.trigger` in a plugin instead of a Vagrantfile.

However, I found that the [docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/v2.3.3/plugins/action-hooks) is completely wrong, that "after" is incorrect!

Actually, you just need to use `prepend`:

```rb
require_relative "action"
action_hook(:goodhosts, :machine_action_halt) do |hook|
  hook.prepend(Action)
end
```

And this is how integrated version of trigger works:

- [lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/d5884388400c2998cdb7f0d51f690c0747128dfc/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb#L248-L268)
- [lib/vagrant/action/builtin/trigger.rb](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/d5884388400c2998cdb7f0d51f690c0747128dfc/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/trigger.rb#L26-L32)

Note: the hooks/middlewares are nested, not sequential.

The community version of trigger always uses `prepend` with "sandwich middleware", i.e. there are operations both before and after the call to the next middleware.

```rb
def call(env)
  before
  @app.call(env)
  after
```

While the integrated version of trigger uses `prepend` for "before" and `append` for "after" with "linear middleware", i.e. there are operations only before the call to the next middleware, as if the hooks were sequential.

```rb
def call(env)
  operation
  @app.call(env)
```

Since provider's actions `halt` and `suspend` are middlewares as well ([hyperv](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/d5884388400c2998cdb7f0d51f690c0747128dfc/plugins/providers/hyperv/action.rb#L50-L66) can be taken as an example), prepended hooks can definitely operate before the halt or suspend action takes effect.